# Memory related error when uploading images in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I am currently using Laravel 8, and I am using AWS LightSail to operate the service.
Among the services, there is a function to upload images of up to 50 MB. When using this function, the following error sometimes occurs.
Currently, php is set to 512M, and Lightsail is using 16 GB of RAM. Any workaround for this error?

error:

> [2022-11-20 19:02:43] local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 536870912
> bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes)
> {"userId":13111,"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError(code: 0): Allowed
> memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864
> bytes) at
> /var/www/project/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php:154)
> [stacktrace]

Which method should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you try to resize or otherwise manipulate the image? Can you share more details about this, and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: Adjusting image capacity is correct!

Comment: What does `Adjusting image capacity is correct!` mean? Try to share more code in what you are trying to achieve. 1) I'm uploading my 50MB file, 2) then I try/catch to do... (fill in the blanks) with an image, then I try to do ...